# How to hide model history in NX 8.0 (Unigraphics)?

Tags: drawing, cad

Assume that I've created a part using [Unigraphics NX](https://www.plm.automation.siemens.com/en_us/products/nx/)  software and need to distribute to a third party. However I would like to hide the part model build history before sending it to a third party. Will it be possible?

Thanks in advance for all the replies.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by exporting the part file as a parasolid and send it. User gets a good geometry, but not the build history.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on "History Mode" on Part Navigator and select "History-Free Mode". Save the Part.

Comment: By changing the history mode - only the display of it gets changed, anyone opening the part can change this mode and get the complete build history.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how this question ended up in this forum, as it is clearly off-topic, but anyway:

It totally depends on what the third-party needs to do with the model and what CAD software they have. If they don't have SIEMENS NX, then the popular export options are the vendor-neutral standards:

- [STEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_10303): `.step`/`.stp` Standard for the Exchange of Product model data
- [IGES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IGES): `.iges`/`.igs`  Initial Graphics Exchange Specification
- [JT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JT_(visualization_format)): `.jt` Jupiter Tessellation

or the open standards:

- [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)): `.stl` Stereolithography created by 3D Systems (mistakenly refered to as Surface/Standard Triangulated Language)
- [OBJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file): `.obj` developed by Wavefront Technologies
- [VRML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VRML): `.wrl` Virtual Reality Modeling Language vector file

beware that exporting from NX to any of the above formats can cause "topology anomalies" ([more info](https://community.sw.siemens.com/s/question/0D54O00006cHzcGSAS/what-is-the-best-way-to-transfer-nx-data-between-two-different-teamcenter-networks)). If the third-party company does have access to SIEMENS PLM products (e.g., NX, SolidEdge...) or any of the CAD software with [ParaSolid engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasolid) (e.g., SolidWorks) then exporting as ParaSolid `.x_t` is the best option. And if they do have NX then another option is to unparametrize your mono-part(s) from `Menu > Edit > Feature > Remove Parameters...`. Then I think they will show up in the "Non-Timestamp Geometry" grouping in the "Part Navigator" panel.